# CloudKit - help adding fields to recordType-

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am a begineer, and so far have worked out how to create a RecordType within CloudKit programmaticaly.

I have searched online and pretty much tried all methods but they don't work most likely relying on another variable that i don't understand yet.

here is my code that works so far for creating the recordType-

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit    

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase     

        let muxID = CKRecordID(recordName: "MUX")                           
        let MUX = CKRecord(recordType: "MUX", recordID: muxID)


        publicDB.saveRecord(MUX) { savedRecord, error in                  // 
            // handle errors here


        }
    }
```

From the apple dev site, it mentions adding Fields like (see below code) but this doesn't work. I think I am getting confused between adding Fields & adding Data into the Fields.

```
MUX["name"] = "peter"
```

I have no other code in my project and my story board has no objects, i would like to learn this programmatically first without any user interaction, to understand the code properly.

Comment: When working in the Development environment adding data to a field that does not yet exist will create that field. Have you written the record after changing the field?

Comment: Thanks Ali- probably not, as I'm new to this, all the code I have is above, if you can help that would be great.

Comment: Can you show where in your code you have put: MUX["name"] = "peter"

Comment: Sure- I added it between, let MUX = CKRecord..........and publicDB.saveRecord........

Comment: OK, so when you say 'it doesn't work', what specifically is wrong? I.e. Is there an error? Do you not see that data on the dashboard?

Comment: Good question, with the above it compiles and no errors are seen, no field is added, but I do get the recordType MUX, just with nothing in it. I did try to use myrecord.setObjectforkey method, but I received a "use of unidentified identifier " I'm not in front of it right now, but I think that was the error...ill be back soon...

Comment: Where are you looking for the record? In the dashboard, under public data and then default zone? Have you checked that the write is not returning an error?

Comment: Yes checking on the dashboard where you said, yes...empty. How do I check for a write error?

Comment: Check 'error' where you currently have '// handle errors here' :) If it is nil then the write worked, otherwise it was rejected. Note that by default CloudKit will not allow you to write a new record over the top of an existing one (you have to read it then change it and write it back). So if 'Mux' already existed before you starting trying to write 'name' to it that is probably your problem - try deleting it in the dashboard and writing from scratch.

Comment: Ahhh that's interesting as it did seem to stop responding after a while, until deleted it and started again, ok that's excellent, I'll add some error handling and see what comes back. I'll post my results back here.

Comment: Hi Ali - new to StackOverflow too - shall i move this to a chat?

Comment: you are a genius! it worked, writing to a new container, i must of been trying to amend or update it with out reading it first...so i need to work out how to read and edit like you said..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise what we found in the comments:

The write was failing because the record already exists. By default CloudKit will not allow a new record to be written over an existing one, it expects you to read the record, modify it and then write the changed record.

For more information, if you have not already viewed it, I recommend [Apple's 2014 WWDC intro to CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/208/).